# jQuery showing script errorObject Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting script error **Object Expected at line: 400 char:1**. The error is on the 1st line of the script. Please suggest how to fix this error.

```
<% taglib prefix="page" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/page"%>
<% taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jso/jstl/core"%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ // error pointing at this line 

    });       
</script>
```

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery library?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: edit the code, showing how are you including jquery, please

Answer (score 0):

can you try below code, I guess you forgot to include jQuery Library

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>              
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ // error pointing at this line 

    });       
</script>
```